SQL Server 2019 datetime column in where condition
In SQL Server 2019 version when we are using a datetime column in where condition it’s returning 0 rows.
We tried to convert it to datetime2 as well but no luck. As the milli/nano seconds are changing and not getting any matches.
Is there any way we can match the datetime value and get results?
select * 
from tab1 
where date = ‘5/28/2024 5:08:17 PM’


format the stored date to the format/precision your inputting.  The downfall is it can't use an index.  Or use >= your date and less than your date+1 min

Are you positive that you have records with exactly that time? Should you be using a > or <?

We tried to convert it to datetime2 as well but no luck. what does that mean? The bad date string alone is enough to cause problems. The unambiguous (ie not affected by locale) date format is YYYYMMDD ..... If you use datetime2, the ISO8601 is also not affected by locale and settings. Don't use the US-only format

As the milli/nano seconds are changing and not getting matched. You can use datetime2(0) which only stores seconds

The question is unclear. I suspect the intention is to store and query time values with second precision. This can be done by:

Using datetime2(0) or datetimeoffset(0) as the type and
Using either strongly typed parameters or an unambiguous date string format. The US-only format doesn't work outside the US and is the source of a lot of pain and actual damages.

For legacy databases that use datetime the only other option is to use a range query between the current second and the next
datetime is a legacy type with several quirks. It was replaced by datetime2 in 2005 but applications still use it.
The unambiguous date literal (ie date string) formats are the unseparated YYYYMMDD format and, in datetime2 and datetimeoffset, the ISO8601 format. That means they aren't affected by the locale or date settings.
Using the correct type and precision
In the following table, the Date field stores values rounded to the second :
CREATE TABLE #TAB1(
    ID int IDENTITY Primary Key, 
    Date datetime2(0) NOT NULL, 
    INDEX IX_TAB1 (Date) 
);
go

INSERT INTO #TAB1 (Date)
VALUE
('2024-05-01 01:01:01.001'),
('2024-05-01 01:01:01.002'),
('2024-05-01 01:01:02');

Despite the millisecond part, only the seconds are stored :
select * from #tab1;
----------------------

ID  Date
1   2024-05-01 01:01:01
2   2024-05-01 01:01:01
3   2024-05-01 01:01:02

Querying for 2024-05-01 01:01:01 returns 2 rows :
select * from #tab1 where Date='2024-05-01 01:01:01';
----------------------------
ID  Date
1   2024-05-01 01:01:01
2   2024-05-01 01:01:01

Using datetime and a range query
In this case the only way that doesn't prevent the use of indexes is to use a range query. The datetime quirks are immediately apparent, as it's not possible to store .001. :
CREATE TABLE #TAB1(
    ID int IDENTITY Primary Key, 
    Date datetime NOT NULL, 
    INDEX IX_TAB1 (Date) 
);
go

INSERT INTO #TAB1 (Date)
VALUEs
('2024-05-01 01:01:01.001'),
('2024-05-01 01:01:01.002'),
('2024-05-01 01:01:02');

select * from #tab1;
--------------------

ID  Date
1   2024-05-01 01:01:01.000
2   2024-05-01 01:01:01.003
3   2024-05-01 01:01:02.000

To get the data in a specific second we need a range query that excludes the next second :
select * from #tab1 
where Date>='2024-05-01 01:01:01' 
  and Date<'2024-05-01 01:01:02';
---------------------------------
ID  Date
1   2024-05-01 01:01:01.000
2   2024-05-01 01:01:01.003

Or, using a parameter :
declare @time datetime2(0)='2024-05-01 01:01:01'

select * from #tab1 
where Date>=@time
  and Date<dateadd(s,1,@time);


Compare your input date with a date range as suggested by xQbert. I prefer using BETWEEN.
SELECT * 
FROM tab1 
WHERE date BETWEEN @inputDate   
               AND DATEADD(minute,1,@inputDate)


No need to proliferate the bad AM/PM date format, better keep it to ISO

I would be a bit more carefull about using between

If no rows are being returned, then no rows match the WHere criteria. This could be for a few reasons.

Confirm you get any data from that table

    SELECT TOP 100 * FROM tab1;


Confirm you actually have records in your table that SHOULD be returned by that query using a broader select statement. Maybe select for the whole month instead of the specific point in time.

   SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE MONTH(date) = 5 AND YEAR(date) = 2024;


Try casting your criteria date to the same type as your date column.

   SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE CAST(date AS DateTime2) = CAST('2024-05-28 05:08:17 PM' AS DATETIME2);


Use a datediff and some other criteria to decide how wide your window should be.

   DECLARE @Criteria datetime = '2024-05-28 17:17:00';
   SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE DATEDIFF(SECOND, date, @Criteria) between 0 AND 60;


All the options are bad because all prevent the use of indexes and/or statistics. The other answers have no such issues. CAST(date AS DateTime2) can use indexes but results in bad statistics

We do have data, and we tried 3rd option as well but it didn’t worked.

Then the issue is a matter of precision then. The ranged approach will likely be the correct one.
